# Java split and replace

Tags: java

I have the following string

```
String path = "(tags:homepage).(tags:project mindshare).(tags:5.5.x).(tags:project 5.x)";
```

I used following code,

```
String delims = "\\.";

String[] tokens = path.split(delims);
int tokenCount = tokens.length;
for (int j = 0; j < tokenCount; j++) {
    System.out.println("Split Output: "+ tokens[j]);
}
```

Current output is

```
Split Output: (tags:homepage)
Split Output: (tags:project mindshare)
Split Output: (tags:5
Split Output: 5
Split Output: x)
Split Output: (tags:project 5
Split Output: x)
```

End goal is to convert this string into

```
String newpath = "(tags:homepage)(tags:project mindshare)(tags:5.5.x)(tags:project 5.x)";
```

Comment: Why not use `replaceAll(").(",")("`?

Comment: Then use 'System.out.print' and not 'println' if you don't want newlines.

Comment: @MuratK. - Its not that simple. He will need to replace only those `.` which are preceeded by a `(`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match only commas not in parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses)

Comment: yeah, I'm aware of replaceAll, thought thats bad way of programming. Want to use some tokenization @MuratK.

Comment: @TheLostMind Yeah, I edited it and provided a replaceAll answer.

Comment: @srinisunka Do as you please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *positive lookbehind* to achieve this :

```
String path = "(tags:homepage).(tags:project mindshare).(tags:5.5.x).(tags:project 5.x)";
String newPath = path.replaceAll("(?<=\\))\\.", ""); // look for periods preceeded by `)`
System.out.println(newPath);
```

O/P :

```
(tags:homepage)(tags:project mindshare)(tags:5.5.x)(tags:project 5.x)
```

Comment: Any other better way of doing it, other then replaceAll ?

Comment: @srinisunka - Yes, there are, split and append for example.. Or even indexOf + subString etc in a loop. But none as elegant as `replaceAll`

Comment: Then use `split()` using the same regex. Then you will get individual tokens which can then be changed @srinisunka

Comment: @srinisunka - If you want a solution without using regex, then check Tunaki's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without using a regular expression, in a clean and simple way, that even supports nested parentheses (for the day you'll need to support them).

What you want to do here is to keep everything that is inside parentheses, so we can just loop over the characters and keep a count of open parentheses. If this count is greater than 0, we add the character (it means we're inside parens); if not, we disregard the character.

```
String path = "(tags:homepage).(tags:project mindshare).(tags:5.5.x).(tags:project 5.x)";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int openParens = 0;
for (char c : path.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '(') openParens++;
    if (openParens > 0) sb.append(c);
    if (c == ')') openParens--;
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This has the advantage that you don't implicly rely on: having a single dot between parens, not having nested parens, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach.

```
System.out.println("(tags:homepage).(tags:project mindshare).(tags:5.5.x).(tags:project 5.x)".replaceAll("\\)\\.\\(", ")("));
```

output is

`(tags:homepage)(tags:project mindshare)(tags:5.5.x)(tags:project 5.x)`