# Regex to capture everything that's not inside parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java Regex, and trying to use Regex to capture data that is not placed between parenthesis, but am having a bit of trouble with lookaheads and lookbehinds. Here's what I have so far: `(?<!\()([A-Z][a-z]?[1-9]*)(?![1-9])(?!\))`

But it doesn't work when the parenthesis is padded by other letters. For example, I'm searching in this string:
`Zn(C2H3Na4O2)2Pb4K3`.

The regex should theoretically capture `Zn, Pb4, and K3` but according to regex101 I'm getting `Zn, He, Na4, Pb4, and K3.` Is there a way to make the regex look ahead to where there is a close parenthesis, as long as there isn't an open parenthesis before it?

Some other examples:
`(NH4)PO3` should output `P and O3` - for this example, the current regex works.
`C3H6O2` should output `C3, H6, and O2`
`K4(H3Mn4)3O5(NH4)2` should output `K4 and O5` only. Right now, the regex outputs `K4, M, and O5.`

Comment: Please provide some good input and good output to further help.

Comment: I've added some more examples - is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9030062/5527985). You can use a lookahead for checking if there's not a `)` ahead without any `(` in between: [`[A-Z][a-z]?\d*(?![^(]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/Ggjjpw/1) for Java: `"[A-Z][a-z]?\\d*(?![^(]*\\))"`