# How to Ignore the desired string during the split in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like

```
pchase_history:array<struct<pchase_channel:string,trans_dt:string,sku_id:string,sold_qty:bigint>>,first_pchase_dt:string,last_pchase_dt:string,trans_cnt:bigint,last_pchase_sku_cnt:bigint,no_of_pchase_days:bigint,lst_pchase_channel:array<struct<pchase_channel:string>>
```

and i need to split it by ',' but don't want to split (array of struct) `array<struct<pchase_channel:string,trans_dt:string,sku_id:string,sold_qty:bigint>>`
I want split method to ignore these array of struct and split the rest of the string.

How can i achieve this by split method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you [tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)? Where are you stuck at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match only commas not in parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses)

Comment: i am not able to do it using split method.I tried by iterating every column then checking for array of struct.

Comment: Then use something else.

Comment: [Regex can't match everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to replace your array of struct **before** doing split like this:

```
String value = "pchase_history:array<struct<pchase_channel:string,trans_dt:string,sku_id:string,sold_qty:bigint>>,first_pchase_dt:string,last_pchase_dt:string,trans_cnt:bigint,last_pchase_sku_cnt:bigint,no_of_pchase_days:bigint,lst_pchase_channel:array<struct<pchase_channel:string>>";

value = value.replaceAll("(array<struct<.*?>>)", "array");
String[] splitedValues = value.split(",");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitedValues));
```

Output:

```
[pchase_history:array, first_pchase_dt:string, last_pchase_dt:string, trans_cnt:bigint, last_pchase_sku_cnt:bigint, no_of_pchase_days:bigint, lst_pchase_channel:array]
```

[Click here to test regex online](https://regex101.com/r/8AbC83/1)