# How to explode in spark with delimiter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, explode

I have a table :

id   itemNames                                         coupons
 1     item (foo bar) is available, soaps                true 
 2     item (bar) is available                           false 
 3     soaps, shampoo                                    false
 4     item (foo bar, bar) is available                  true
 5     item (foo bar, bar) is available, (soap, shampoo) true
 6     null                                              false

I want to explode this to

id      itemNames                                          coupons
  1  item (foo bar) is available                        true
  1  soaps                                              true 
  2 item (bar) is available                            false
  3  soaps                                              false
  3  shame                                              false
  4  item (foo bar, bar) is available                   true
  5  item (foo bar, bar) is available                   true
  6  (soap, shampoo)                                    true
  6  null                                               true

when I do :

```
 df.withColumn("itemNames", explode(split($"itemNames", "[,]")))
```

I am getting :

```
itemNames                                          coupons
item (foo bar) is available                        true       
soaps                                              true 
item (bar) is available                            false
soaps                                              false
shampoo                                            false
item (foo bar,                                     true
bar) is available                                  true 
(soap,                                             true    
shampoo)                                           true
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how can I correct this ? The one pattern common here is the comma appears inside ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With UDF and inspired by [Regex to match only commas not in parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses) :

```
val df = List(
  ("item (foo bar) is available, soaps", true),
  ("item (bar) is available", false),
  ("soaps, shampoo", false),
  ("item (foo bar, bar) is available", true),
  ("item (foo bar, bar) is available, (soap, shampoo)", true)
).
  toDF("itemNames", "coupons")
df.show(false)

val regex = Pattern.compile(
  ",         # Match a comma\n" +
    "(?!       # only if it's not followed by...\n" +
    " [^(]*    #   any number of characters except opening parens\n" +
    " \\)      #   followed by a closing parens\n" +
    ")         # End of lookahead",
  Pattern.COMMENTS)

val customSplit = (value: String) => regex.split(value)
val customSplitUDF = udf(customSplit)
val result = df.withColumn("itemNames", explode(customSplitUDF($"itemNames")))
result.show(false)
```

Output is:

```
+--------------------------------+-------+
|itemNames                       |coupons|
+--------------------------------+-------+
|item (foo bar) is available     |true   |
| soaps                          |true   |
|item (bar) is available         |false  |
|soaps                           |false  |
| shampoo                        |false  |
|item (foo bar, bar) is available|true   |
|item (foo bar, bar) is available|true   |
| (soap, shampoo)                |true   |
+--------------------------------+-------+
```

If "trim" is required, can be added to "customSplit" easly.

Comment: Im getting - Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (string) => array<string>).

Comment: Can you please provide more trace, what is the reason for failure?

Comment: Updated the query with stack trace. Can you please let me know if I am doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Nvm, I think its NPE.

Comment: more trace is required, in provided specified  only that function failed. Reason (NPE, etc) can be deeper in trace. If its NPE, guess, UDF can be improved.

Comment: I think it is because some rows have empty values(null). Do I need to update the udf to check for empty rows ?

Comment: yes, empty rows and null values can be checked in UDF.

Answer (score 1):

your problem doesn't have a pattern to split the string from backwards. The below is a workaround and works for this particular case. I'm dividing by "available," using the lookbehind operation. Try this out in your dataframe explode

```
scala> "item (foo bar) is available, soaps".split("(?<=available),")
res41: Array[String] = Array(item (foo bar) is available, " soaps")

scala> "item (foo bar) is available, soaps".split("(?<=available),").length
res42: Int = 2

scala> "item (foo bar, bar) is available".split("(?<=available),")
res44: Array[String] = Array(item (foo bar, bar) is available)

scala> "item (foo bar, bar) is available".split("(?<=available),").length
res45: Int = 1
```

**EDIT1**

```
scala> "item (foo bar, bar) is empty, (soap, shampoo)".split("(?<=available|empty),").length
res1: Int = 2

scala>
```

Comment: Yeah.. This is will only when the values have available at the end. But I am looking for a more generic approach because my data also have other values

Comment: if you know the distinct other values you can alternate them.. see my EDIT1, otherwise you need to write a udf(), do the regex and return an array, then explode.