# PHP preg_split regex by a given delimiter where not between []

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need some regex help. I want to explode as string by a given delimiter (this could change) but in this case a comma. But only, if that comma is not in between square brackets

Here is my example string :

```
name:in:['john','jane'],name:in:['doe']
```

My desired outcome :

```
Array(
    [0] => name:in:['john,'jane']
    [1] => name:in['doe']
)
```

I feel i'm close but this is not quite working :

```
$filters = preg_split("~$delimiter(?![^[]]*\))~", $filters);
```

Current output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => name:in:['john'
    [1] => 'jane']
    [2] => name:in:['doe']
)
```

It would be great if someone could help, but also explain the regex by breaking it down into its parts.

Comment: Should be `\]`, not `\)` i.e. `preg_split("~$delimiter(?![^[]*\])~", $filters)` https://3v4l.org/srmQn

Comment: That's spot on Nick. Would be great if you could post it as an answer with a description of the parts, then happy to accept !

Comment: I can't post an answer as the question has been closed as a duplicate, but there's a good explanation of how this regex works (for `()` instead of `[]`) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses/9030062#9030062

Comment: I somewhat disagree with this being marked as a duplicate. Regex can be very fiddly and and the first 'duplicate' is a different programming language. Anyway, regex is regex, and stackoverflow gods rule us all. Thanks @nick