# PHP Explode string between two characters to arrays? (Noob question)

Tags: php, arrays, string, split, explode

Hello :) I am a beginner in PHP.
I tried several times but did not succeed

I would like to parse a String like : 
`[1,[01,11,12],[20,21,22]]`
to

```
`
arr[0][0]=>1
arr[1][0]=>01
arr[1][1]=>11
arr[1][2]=>12
arr[2][0]=>20
arr[2][1]=>21
arr[2][2]=>22
`
```

Comment: How many levels of nested arrays can there be?

Comment: go to php.net and find "eval" function, try to play with that

Comment: @Nick It will always be a bidimensionnal array

Comment: [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: @AnatoliyR "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question." Rasmus Lerdorf, PHP Co-Author and BDFL

Comment: @Sammitch agree with the quote, but eval() _is_ the answer for the question whether it's right or wrong. I would not use eval for security reason, but if code complexity is the issue, it's much easier to use eval rather than parse the string and build an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your string on a comma that is not enclosed by `[` and `]` using this regex (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses/9030062#9030062)) with [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
,(?![^\[]*\])
```

and then trim surrounding `[` and `]` from the resultant parts and split those strings on commas into succeeding elements of the output array. For example:

```
$string = '[1,[01,11,12] ,4 ,5, [20,21,22]]';
$parts = preg_split('/,(?![^\[]*\])/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$output = array();
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $part = trim($part, '[] ');
    $output[] = explode(',', $part);
}
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 01
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 12
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 22
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/v4b9i)

If you're **100% certain** of the source and safety of the string, you can also just use [`eval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
eval("\$output = $string;");
```

The result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sample data's `01` is typo that should have been `10`, then your input is valid json.

In this case, you only need to decode the json, then unconditionally cast each element as an array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9Fr0X))

```
$json = '[1,[10,11,12],[20,21,22]]';
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($v) => (array) $v,
        json_decode($json)
    )
);
```

It is generally a bad idea to parse a valid json string with regular expressions.  Even more risky is PHP's `eval()` -- which may expose your application to known vulnerabilities.