# R strsplit ignore some text

Tags: r, strsplit, ignore

I'm working on a survey, and many of the written categories on an answer are separated by commas. I have used gsub successfully in order to separate them, like this.

`sss6 <- str_trim(unlist(strsplit(aiprm$step_do_you_anticipate, split=",")))`

I have successfully separated strings like these, so I can count them each correctly in order to make visualizations.

*Grammar, None of the above, Grammar, Subject matter expertise, Grammar, Subject matter expertise, Bias, Grammar, Subject matter expertise, Bias, Fact-checking*

The problem now is that I have text with parenthesis and commas inside, and I would like that the commas inside the parenthesis "()" are ignored. Here are some examples of that.

*Ad copy, JavaScript code, headlines, compelling copy, commercial ideas, Ad copy, Title & meta description, Idea generation (topics, headlines), Code,  Idea generation (topics, headlines), Ad copy, Idea generation (topics, headlines)*

Is there any way to tell the strsplit() function to not separate or ignore the commas that are inside the parenthesis? The main problem is **(topics, headlines)**

Thanks!

Comment: Is the problematic string in parentheses *always* "(topics, headlines)" or will it change? Also, do you want to keep the problematic part in parentheses or do you want to remove it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/12109788/jpsmith Hello, it will never change, and I want to keep it. It's always the same, it repeats a lot .

Answer (score 1):

Horrible (and really slow) solution:

```
chrs        <- strsplit(s, "")[[1]]
commas      <- as.integer(chrs == ",")
parenthesis <- cumsum(chrs == "(" | chrs == ")")
ind         <- which((commas == 1) & (parenthesis %% 2 == 0))

sapply(seq_along(ind), function(i) {
  start <- ifelse(i == 1, 1, ind[i - 1] + 2)
  end   <- ind[i] - 1
  paste(chrs[start:end], collapse = "")
})
```

Best way to go about it is probably to use a regex. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses).

Comment: That link is a nice find - you should just steal the first regex from that thread and adapt it to R - `trimws(strsplit(x, ",(?![^(]*\\))", perl=TRUE)[[1]])` works really well from what I can see.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case, since you note that the problematic string within parentheses is *always* the same ("topics, headlines"), and if you're up for a slight modification, this could be easily done by subbing out the comma within the phrase with another non-comma punctuation, such as a hyphen, ie:

```
gsub("topics, headlines", "topics-headlines", aiprm$step_do_you_anticipate)
```

Which will just require you replacing the `aiprm$step_do_you_anticipate` in your original code with the above:

```
sss6 <- stringr::str_trim(unlist(strsplit(
  gsub("topics, headlines", "topics-headlines", aiprm$step_do_you_anticipate), 
  split=",")))

# [1] "Ad copy"                            "JavaScript code"                   
# [3] "headlines"                          "compelling copy"                   
# [5] "commercial ideas"                   "Ad copy"                           
# [7] "Title & meta description"           "Idea generation (topics-headlines)"
# [9] "Code"                               "Idea generation (topics-headlines)"
# [11] "Ad copy"                            "Idea generation (topics-# headlines)"
```

If you really wanted the commas, you could sub back out quickly:

```
gsub("topics-headlines", "topics, headlines", sss6) 

# [1] "Ad copy"                             "JavaScript code"                    
# [3] "headlines"                           "compelling copy"                    
# [5] "commercial ideas"                    "Ad copy"                            
# [7] "Title & meta description"            "Idea generation (topics, headlines)"
# [9] "Code"                                "Idea generation (topics, headlines)"
# [11] "Ad copy"                             "Idea generation (topics, headlines)"
```

As an aside, you may also want to look into `tidyr::separate_longer_delim()`:

```
aiprm$comma_replaced <- gsub("topics, headlines", "topics-headlines", aiprm$step_do_you_anticipate)

tidyr::separate_longer_delim(aiprm, comma_replaced, ",")

#                        comma_replaced
#1                              Ad copy
#2                      JavaScript code
#3                            headlines
#4                      compelling copy
#5                     commercial ideas
#6                              Ad copy
#7             Title & meta description
#8   Idea generation (topics-headlines)
#9                                 Code
#10  Idea generation (topics-headlines)
#11                             Ad copy
#12  Idea generation (topics-headlines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77011474/r-strsplit-ignore-some-text/77011673#comment135762119_77011673) to a full answer as it should be more direct an answer without modifying the original string:

Example data:

```
x <- "Ad copy, JavaScript code, headlines, compelling copy, commercial ideas, Ad copy, Title & meta description, Idea generation (topics, headlines), Code, Idea generation (topics, headlines), Ad copy, Idea generation (topics, headlines)"
```

Regex splitting adapted to R from [this Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9030036/regex-to-match-only-commas-not-in-parentheses) linked in [@weakCoder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77011673/496803):

```
trimws(strsplit(x, ",(?![^(]*\\))", perl=TRUE)[[1]])

## [1] "Ad copy"                             "JavaScript code"                    
## [3] "headlines"                           "compelling copy"                    
## [5] "commercial ideas"                    "Ad copy"                            
## [7] "Title & meta description"            "Idea generation (topics, headlines)"
## [9] "Code"                                "Idea generation (topics, headlines)"
##[11] "Ad copy"                             "Idea generation (topics, headlines)"
```